# Ingnorar @ en C#

Tags: html, c#, razor

Estoy construyendo una vista donde uso una etiqueta `<a>` de esta forma:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/maps/@14.5694796,-90.5216991,18.5z" target="_blank">
    <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Dirección Casa
</a>
```

El problema es que detecta la `@` como que se esta incrustando código de C#...necesito ignorar este carácter,  ya que como podrán ver en el código, la idea es abrir otra pestaña con las coordenadas en google maps.

El archivo es un **.cshtml**

Saludos

Comment: Ese html lo usas dentro de un `.html` o es un `aspx` o `.cshtml` ? para entender porque una view puede reconocer el @ como codigo c# solo si usas Razor

Comment: Así es @LeandroTuttini, uso .cshtml

Comment: Duplica el arroba para escaparlo, @@ va a dar como resultado @

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dentro de razor el caracter `@` sirve para escapar los símbolos, por ende, si necesitas usar el `@` simplemente debes duplicarlo

Por lo cual, `@@` mostrará `@` en el html generado.

Tome de referencia la [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3626870/5213794) de [ajay_whiz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/398368/ajay-whiz) en [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com)